# Create a method to return listend. And change adding method that it uses listend

Tags: c#, linked-list, console-application

I've this program and my tasks are:

1. To create a method that returns the current end of the list or get the end of the list from the method for appending have it delivered and
2. To set the value of the end of list instance after appending new elements to the current end of the list and then call the method to append new list items with this value.

```
class Node
{
    string info;
    Node next;
    public void SetInfo(string InfoNew)

    {
        info = InfoNew;
        next = null;
    }

    public void Add(string InfoNew)
    {
        if (next == null)
        {
            next = new Node();
            next.SetInfo(InfoNew);
        }
        else
            next.Add(InfoNew);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node listStart = new Node();
        listStart.Add("node 1");
        for (int node = 2; node < 4; node++)
            listStart.Add("node " + node);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my solution. It works. But I'm no sure if this is correct.

```
class Node
{
    string info;
    Node next;

    public void SetInfo(string InfoNew)
    {
        info = InfoNew;
        next = null;
    }

    public Node Add(string InfoNew)
    {
        if (next == null)
        {
            next = new Node();
            next.SetInfo(InfoNew);
        }
        else
            next.Add(InfoNew);
        return next;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(info);
        if (next != null)
            next.Print();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public Node End()
    {
        Node ptr = next;
        while (ptr.next != null)
            ptr = ptr.next;              
        return ptr;
    }    
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node listStart = new Node();
        Node listEnd = new Node();
        listStart.Add("node 1");
        for (int node = 2; node < 4; node++)
            listEnd = listStart.Add("node " + node);
        listStart.Print();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"It works. But I'm no sure if this is correct"_ - did you debug it?  Unit tests?

Comment: I did debug it and the Print()-method shows all elements correct. But I'm not sure if listEnd is really the end of list. How do I do unit tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the right way to do it, isn't it?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node listStart = new Node();
        Node listEnd = new Node();
        listStart.Add("node 1");
        listEnd = listStart;
        for (int node = 2; node < 4; node++)
            listEnd = listEnd.Add("node " + node);
        listStart.Print();
    }
}
```